# TreeListView, tryringto combine listview and tree

Tags: wpf, silverlight, listview, treeview

I have treeView that is bounded to a class that imlements the interface - IHaveValue.

Inside countryies, I want the inner items that are also IHaveValue to act as ListView,
that allow grouping.

I've seen this question but is doesn't helped:
[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371883/treelistview-with-columns-generated-and-populated-by-observablecollection)

[image]