# How to add a Datagridview into a Scatterviewitem?

Tags: c#, datagrid, scatterview

I am trying to display the contents of different tables dynamically using scatterview, is there an easy way to do that. Right now I have the results of a query in DatagridView and I want to add it to a ScatterViewItem. I tried directly assigning, however I must be doing something wrong here. Do I need to bind it to the xaml code?

```
dgv = QueryResult();
svi.Content = dgv.DataSource;
```

Comment: I am trying to do this using code and not by binding it. Meaning that the datagrid will be dynamic. Any ideas, I currently get a blank datagrid when I try assigning it to the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for this question was already there, my mistake I did not search that well. 
The last post in :
[Can I programmatically add a row to a WPF datagrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880959/can-i-programmatically-add-a-row-to-a-wpf-datagrid?lq=1)

Moderators please flag appropriately.

Thanks