# CS1061 error when populating data grid rows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to populate rows in my data grid and I'm getting a 1061 error. How do I fix this. Second, how can I set the number of empty rows?

C#

```
            string[] row1 = new string[] { "a", "", "Form 1" };
            string[] row2 = new string[] { "b", "", "Form 2" };
            string[] row3 = new string[] { "S ", "", "Form 3" };
            string[] row4 = new string[] { "d ", "", "Form 4" };
            string[] row5 = new string[] { "e ", "", "Form 5" };
            string[] row6 = new string[] { "f ", "", "Form 6" };
            object[] rows = new object[] { row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6 };

            foreach (string[] rowArray in rows)
            {
                election_grid.Rows.Add(rowArray);
            }
```

XAML

```
<DataGrid x:Name="election_grid" Grid.Column ="1" Grid.Row="30" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Election" Width="150"/>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Default?" Width="150"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Other Election" Width="150"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Election Effective Date" Width="150"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date Election must be filed" Width="200"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Produces a CS1061 error

Comment: _"a 1061 error"_ - read [ask], provide the entire error, show your research.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler tells you that Datagrid does not have Rows (it has Items)

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704724/programmatically-add-column-rows-to-wpf-datagrid) if you want to add them manually.

And my advice: it would be better to bind to a List (ObservableCollection). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011444/manually-add-rows-in-wpf-datagrid)