# Binding a WPF DatGrid to a 2 dimensional array

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, multidimensional-array, wpfdatagrid

I have a little problem concerning databinding, infact I have a WPF project where I have a DataGrid Control that I want to bind to a two dimensional array, tried to bind dirrectly using datacontext but it didn't work, it showed all the time an error telling me that the array is not one dimensional, can any one show me how to do ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two questions might help you:

[How do I bind a WPF DataGrid to a variable number of columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320089/how-do-i-bind-a-wpf-datagrid-to-a-variable-number-of-columns/8890435#8890435)

[programmatically add column & rows to WPF Datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704724/programatically-add-column-rows-to-wpf-datagrid/8892340#8892340)

You need to 'transform' one dimension of array to columns and use the other array dimension as rows.