# WPF insert grid column at particular place

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a way to add a new column to a grid between 2 other columns in runtime?

Comment: Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704724/programatically-add-column-rows-to-wpf-datagrid , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514525(v=vs.90).aspx and http://www.paulstovell.com/dynamic-datagrid

Comment: @Peretz that does not answer the question. Not in the designer but in runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can just do:

```
var index = 1; //column index to insert
var colDef = new ColumnDefinition() { Width=new GridLength(200) };
MyGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Insert(index, colDef);
```