# How to make xaml stackpanel have one or two colums

Tags: xaml, stackpanel

I want my stackpanel to display one or two rows, dependen on a bool value.
I want it to fill for both if there is only one.
how do I do that? - or should i use grid?

Comment: If you post some code i can help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a grid for this. There is many ways you can do this on. You can make a grid with 2 rows then set heigt to *. Or you can do this in code when the bool is true create a new row.

Here is how you can add row/columns in code.
[programmatically add column & rows to WPF Datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704724/programatically-add-column-rows-to-wpf-datagrid)