# how to show a list property in DataGrid properly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a class with 6 properties, "CompletePosition", "ActivityNumber", "ActivityDescription", "Duration", "WeatherWindow" and "Critiria" which i try to show in a datagrid. At the moment i set the DataGrid's ItemsSource to a IEnumerable.

As you may have figued out, my problem is that "Critiria" just shows as "(Collection)". i would like it to be, so to say, expanded, and each element of the list to be shown in it's own column. Is this possible?

[image: current]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot have another Grid within a GridCell. Depending on the nature of the content in the collection, you could simply explode the collection into a comma delimited string and display that.

Say for example your collection is:

```
[Apples, Oranges, Pears]
```

You could do `String.Join(",", collection);` to get a string separated by commas.

Result would be: `Apples, Oranges, Pears`.

Though this relies on the content of your collection.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but what I meant was not to have another grid, but to make it look like there wasn't a collection but indestead 6 properties. so there wasnt a column named "Criteria" but indestead 6 columns. is this posible? to "trick" datagrid into thinking that there is 6 prperties?

Comment: You can add those properties to whatever class you're binding to the DataGrid. And then before binding, you can populate those 6 properties with the values of your collection.

Comment: But i can only do it hardcoded? most of the times it'll be 6, but not every time. No way to do it dynamic?

Comment: Well, I guess can you loop through your collection and dynamically add Columns to the DataGrid. See something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704724/programatically-add-column-rows-to-wpf-datagrid