# How to create rows consist of labels and textboxes by code in a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, textbox, wpfdatagrid

I'm using visual studio C# .
I want to add rows in a data grid (label and a textbox next to it), and the numbers of rows should varies, for example it's 5, 10 or 1000... . At the end I need to grab the values of those textboxes.
Any idea of how the code should be?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Find a data grid tutorial and follow that. If you get stuck and have a specific question then come back here.

Comment: Avoid posting questions where you basically ask everyone to code a solution for you. Instead try something on your own, read tutorials first and then post questions about specific issues here.

Comment: It's just that I'm new to C# and I have a project which i must get it done by tomorrow, I used to work with JAVA. I'm searching for the right tutorial..

Comment: That is exactly what SO is NOT there for, this is not a "do my homework for me" site.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial
Read This.
Code.
Then Ask !
That would certainly be much more helpful to you too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone, It seems that the real question is how to deal with WPF DataGrid,
I searched it online and found many solutions like :
[programmatically add column & rows to WPF Datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704724/programatically-add-column-rows-to-wpf-datagrid)

Thanks.