# How to programmatically form an observable collection and bind it to a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, observablecollection

I have a problem which i'd divide in two steps:

**Problem1.**

Form an observable collection of strings and bind it to a datagrid

```
ObservableCollection<string[]> octest = new ObservableCollection<string[]>();
var el = new string[6] {"1","2","3", "4", "5", "6" };
octest.Add(el);
octest.Add(el);
octest.Add(el);
dtgResults.ItemsSource = octest;
```

the problem is that the binding results in the image below:

[image]

---

**Problem 2**

The same but now with an array of strings but with mixed elements (e.g. 3 strings and 3 doubles)

thank you

--EDIT-- for CBreeze

I have done that:

```
  ObservableCollection<TestModel> t = new ObservableCollection<TestModel>();
  var t1 = new TestModel();
  t.Add(t1);
  t.Add(t1);
  t.Add(t1);
  dtgResults.ItemsSource = t;
 }
}

public class TestModel
{
  public TestModel()
  {
    TestDouble1 = new string[3];
    TestDouble1[0] = "A";
    TestDouble1[1] = "B";
    TestDouble1[2] = "C";
  }
  public string[] TestDouble1 { get; set; }
}
```

and the result is:

[image]

Comment: You should post your datagrid columns definitions to see where the problem is

Comment: And what is your expected result?

Comment: @Pikoh the datagrid has no colum: do you think that this is the problem?   <DataGrid Name="dtgResults" Background="Transparent"   />

Comment: @VadimMartynov I would like to see | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | and then be able to customize the header per each column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from

> [programmatically add column & rows to WPF Datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704724/programatically-add-column-rows-to-wpf-datagrid)

you can do that:

```
string[] columnLabels = new string[] { "Column 0", "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3", "Column 4", "Column 5" };

foreach (string label in columnLabels)
{
 DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
 column.Header = label;
 column.Binding = new Binding(label.Replace(' ', '_'));

 dtgResults.Columns.Add(column);
}

int[] ivalues = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
string[] svalues = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };

dynamic row = new ExpandoObject();

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{

 switch (i)
 {
  case 0:
  case 1:
  case 2:
   string str = columnLabels[i].Replace(' ', '_');
   ((IDictionary<String, Object>)row)[str] = ivalues[i];
   break;

   case 3:
   case 4:
   case 5:
    string str2 = columnLabels[i].Replace(' ', '_');
    ((IDictionary<String, Object>)row)[str2] = svalues[i - 3];
    break;

 }
}

dtgResults.Items.Add(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind your `ObservableCollection` to a `Model`;

`ObservableCollection<TestModel> octest = new ObservableCollection<TestModel>();`

Create your `TestModel`;

```
public class TestModel
{
    public double TestDouble1 { get; set; }
    public double TestDouble2 { get; set; }
    public double TestDouble3 { get; set; }
    public string TestString1 { get; set; }
    public string TestString2 { get; set; }
    public string TestString3 { get; set; }
}
```

You then need to actually create a `TestModel`....

`TestModel newTestModel = new TestModel();`

Add new values to `TestModel`.....

```
newTestModel.TestString1 = "Hello"
newTestModel.TestString2 = "Hello"
newTestModel.TestString3 = "Hello"
```

Finally add the new `TestModel` to the `ObservableCollection`;

`octest.Add(newTestModel);`

Comment: I can't since I am not aware of the number of elements. So I don't know how many TestDouble or TestString are there since it's something decided at runtime.

Comment: Add an `Array` into the `Model` then instead of using `String` and `Double`, even better add a `Dictionary` that takes `String` and `Double`, something like: `var myDict = new Dictionary<string, List<double>>();`