# Datagrid row foreground colour change not working

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, row, foreground

this is the continuation to :

> [How to programmatically form an observable collection and bind it to a datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35339551/how-to-programmatically-form-an-observable-collection-and-bind-it-to-a-datagrid/35342033#35342033)

so I build a datagrid through:

```
string[] columnLabels = new string[] { "Column 0", "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3", "Column 4", "Column 5" };

foreach (string label in columnLabels)
{
  DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
  column.Header = label;
  column.Binding = new Binding(label.Replace(' ', '_'));

  dtgResults.Columns.Add(column);
}

int[] ivalues = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
string[] svalues = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };

dynamic row = new ExpandoObject();

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{

  switch (i)
  {
   case 0:
   case 1:
   case 2:
    string str = columnLabels[i].Replace(' ', '_');
    ((IDictionary<String, Object>)row)[str] = ivalues[i];
    break;

   case 3:
   case 4:
   case 5:
    string str2 = columnLabels[i].Replace(' ', '_');
    ((IDictionary<String, Object>)row)[str2] = svalues[i - 3];
  break;

  }
}
dtgResults.Items.Add(row);
```

so now I would like to be able to change foreground colour here not having to go to datagrid_autogeneratecolumns.

```
foreach (var item in dtgResults.Items)
{
    var row = dtgResults.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
    row.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
}
```

but that doesn't change a think

Comment: It changes the text color for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your xaml

```
<DataGrid Name="dtg" Background="Transparent">
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
       <EventSetter Event="DataGridCell.Loaded" Handler="DataGridCell_Load"/>
          <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
              </Style>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
```

and then in code-behind

```
private void DataGridCell_Load(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
  cell.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
}
```

Comment: OK thanx by doing this I get cell content too and row but how about the column?

Comment: it's the other way round: you get the column by   int column = cell.Column.DisplayIndex; and the row by int row = -1;
DataGridRow rowContainer = parentDataGrid.GetRow(0);
for (int iii = 0; iii < parentDataGrid.Items.Count; iii++)
{
            if (parentDataGrid.Items[iii] == rowContainer.Item)
            {
              row = iii;
              break;
            }
          }