# Adding A Row To A DataGrid In WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

So in WinForms you can easily add a row, for example

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(user.Handle, c);
```

But in WPF, when I try to use a DataGrid there is no 'Rows' property.
Is there any way to do this in WPF that doesn't consist of an insane amount of lines of code or a lot of messing with XAML?

Comment: Bind a DataTable to your DataGridView and add a new row in DataTable

Comment: Take a look at this sample, using List<> : http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/details-row/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [programatically add column & rows to WPF Datagrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704724/programatically-add-column-rows-to-wpf-datagrid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's this simple :

```
// add a row    
DataGrid.Items.Add(new DataItem()); 

// add a column
DataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn());
```

Please refer this link for more, http://wpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=34065

Or if you don't like to add rows directly like that, use a collection as source. 
Bind the Grid to a List (Observable collection). Add items to that list.
**Result: new rows show up in the grid.**

Answer (score 3):

if you are not binding it to any source (i.e DataTable, List etc) try

```
dataGridView1.Items.Add(new DataItem { Column1 = "a", Column2 = "b" });
```