# How to show a list of data in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml

### The point here is that I want to replicate the following example within XAML-page. Difference here is that I don't know beforehand the quantity of data to show, so it has to be kind of generic one.

Let's say, I have some model `UserModel.cs` which looks like this:

```
class UserModel
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    int BirthYear { get; set; }
}
```

and I have some view `DataViewer.cs` which looks like this:

```
class DataViewer
{
    static void ShowData()
    {
        var users = new List<UserModel>() 
        {
            new UserModel() { FirstName = "Thomas", BirthYear = 1995 },
            new UserModel() { FirstName = "Arthur", BirthYear = 1991 },
            new UserModel() { FirstName = "John", BirthYear = 2000 }
        };

        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{user.FirstName} was born in {user.BirthYear}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could place a `datagrid` inside your `XAML` and then add rows/columns to it dynamically. This is a post with information on adding the rows/columns dynamically: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704724/programmatically-add-column-rows-to-wpf-datagrid)

Comment: I don't fully understand your need. Do you want to show a list of UserModel or a list of different type of data ? Exemple : a list composed of UserModel and CustomerModel and any other Model you might have ? Or you need to display a collection which might be updated in the future and want that changes to be reflected on the user interface ?

Comment: @Nk54 I want to have CollectionView which will be populated with data from database. Let's assume that I want to grab `UsersModels` from DB and display their names on my page

Comment: Is it CollectionView from Xamarin Forms ? Here is how : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout

Comment: @Nk54 yes, and I'm trying to make it in XAML, not C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow the given exemple on the documentation which you can [find here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout).
I can't help you more that the official documentation as it is very solid on CollectionView : a lot of exemple and how to make it working.

Anyway here is a starting point :

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding BirthYear}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Assuming you have a collection property called Users in your ViewModel.