# WPF DataGrid Columns in Style or resource

Tags: wpf, datagrid, resources

Is it possible to declare `DataGrid` columns in a style or as a resource?
I would like to do something like this:

```
<....Resources>
    <DataGridColumns x:Key="dgcDataGridColumns">
        <DataGridTextColumn />
        <DataGridTextColumn />
    </DataGridColumns
</....Resources>

<DataGrid Columns="{StaticResource dgcDataGridColumns}" />
```

The reason is that i have to share the column definition for 4 different `DataGrids`. Any way to achieve this? Best would be without code behind!

Comment: I guess it depends on the Datagrid provider... I know that Xceed datagrid allow to define columns in resources, but I don't know for others. Which one are you using ? The WPF toolkit one ?

Comment: I am using the .NET 4 WPF DataGrid

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Columns property of the DataGrid has no setter so it is not possibly. You can however do something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <Controls:DataGrid x:Key="PersonDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding .}" x:Shared="False">
        <Controls:DataGrid.Columns>
            <Controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <Controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        </Controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    </Controls:DataGrid>

</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource PersonDataGrid}" DataContext="{Binding Path=Customers}"></ContentControl>
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource PersonDataGrid}" DataContext="{Binding Path=Employees}"></ContentControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Ok this seems to do the trick. But how i can apply a style to the content of a contentcontrol (so actually to the DataGrid)?

Comment: Please post a new question, hard to answer in comments.

Answer (score 29):

x:Shared helps to avoid the exception MattS423 has got.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Key="dgtcFirstName" x:Shared="False" Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Key="dgtcSecondName" x:Shared="False" Header="Second Name" Binding="{Binding SecondName}"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="200" Name="dataGrid1" Width="200">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="dgtcFirstName"/>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="dgtcSecondName"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="200" Name="dataGrid2" Width="200">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="dgtcSecondName"/>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="dgtcFirstName"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This was a great solution for me to avoid copy and pasting the same column definitions over and over. I find it strange that x:Shared didn't show up in the intellisense though, but works well all the same

Comment: never new about Shared on resources... solves multiple problems for me including reusing datagrid columns for multiple datagrids, thanks much

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can, as in that situation you aren't specifying a template or a style, but the actual Column object.  I don't think the data grids play nicely when sharing like that; I think you'll get an exception to the extent of "This UIElement is already the child of another UIElement".

So I tried the following...slightly different than what you're talking about.  but I got this exception:

{"DataGridColumn with Header '' already exists in the Columns collection of a DataGrid. DataGrids cannot share columns and cannot contain duplicate column instances.\r\nParameter name: item"}

with this XAML:

```
         <Grid.Resources>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Key="MyColumn" />
        </Grid.Resources>
          <DataGrid>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="MyColumn" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <DataGrid>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="MyColumn" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this, even though it doesn't answer the  question.  The inclusion of the exception text helped me find the answer I needed (x:Shared="False").