# How do I Inherit DataGridColumns

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I'm writing a `UserControl` with two `DataTemplates` in the resources:

**DataTemplate 1**

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="Template1">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="DataGridSelectionChanged">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="FilePath" Width="Auto" SortMemberPath="FilePath">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock  Padding="4,1" Text="{Binding FilePath}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="FileSize" Width="Auto" SortMemberPath="FileSize">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock  Padding="4,1" Text="{Binding FileSize}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</DataTemplate>
```

**DataTemplate2**

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="Template2">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="DataGridSelectionChanged">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="FilePath" Width="Auto" SortMemberPath="FilePath">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock  Padding="4,1" Text="{Binding FilePath}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="FileSize" Width="Auto" SortMemberPath="FileSize">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock  Padding="4,1" Text="{Binding FileSize}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="FileCreator" Width="Auto" SortMemberPath="FileCreator">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock  Padding="4,1" Text="{Binding FileCreator}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="FileCreated" Width="Auto" SortMemberPath="FileCreated">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock  Padding="4,1" Text="{Binding FileCreated}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</DataTemplate>
```

With a `DataTemplateSelector` I decide which `DataTemplate` should be used. Everything just works fine.

But as you can see DataTemplate2 has the same two cells as DataTemplate1 plus two additional. This is just an small example. In my application DataTemplate1 has around 15 columns. And with DataTemplate2 there are another 10 columns.

My question now is: Is there a possibility that I can inherit(or so) the columns from another `DataGrid` inside a `DataTemplate` and add additional columns?

Comment: What about just using the same set of columns for both, and toggling the Visibility of columns based on some value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the Columns as Resource and Refer them in the DataGrid as resources. Make sure you should marked them as x:Shared as false to avoid the conflict.
Refer below code.

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Key="FilePath" x:Shared="False" Header="FilePath" Width="Auto" SortMemberPath="FilePath">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock  Padding="4,1" Text="{Binding FilePath}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Key="FileSize" x:Shared="False" Header="FileSize" Width="Auto" SortMemberPath="FileSize">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock  Padding="4,1" Text="{Binding FileSize}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Template1">
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="DataGridSelectionChanged">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="FilePath"/>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="FileSize"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Template2">
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="DataGridSelectionChanged">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="FilePath"/>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="FileSize"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="FileCreator" Width="Auto" SortMemberPath="FileCreator">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock  Padding="4,1" Text="{Binding FileCreator}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="FileCreated" Width="Auto" SortMemberPath="FileCreated">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock  Padding="4,1" Text="{Binding FileCreated}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Refer this link as well [WPF DataGrid Columns in Style or resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716123/wpf-datagrid-columns-in-style-or-resource)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no inherit possibility in columns in datagrid, but what I suggest is --

- Create a customGrid control and add all the common columns to it.
- Use this grid in your template and add the columns that make sense for that template.

So you will have, BaseGrid with columns 1,2,3,4 and then you can use this baseGrid and add columns 5,6 in one template and 7,8 in another template.
You will have 2 resulting grids, one with columns 1,2,3,4,5,6 and another with 1,2,3,4,7,8

`DataGrid.Columns` is a collection of columns and you can add stuff into it whenever you wish for.