# How to make an XAML resource be reusable across controls?

Tags: c#, wpf

I currently have the following code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgAppRevision" Margin="0,50,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" MouseDoubleClick="dgdc"  RowStyle="{StaticResource appStyle}"  Grid.Row="1">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Python">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image x:Name="checkImage" Width="30" Height="30" Source="pack://application:,,,/ProjectTracker;component/Icons/GreenCheck.png" />
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=python_done}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/ProjectTracker;component/Icons/RedX.png" TargetName="checkImage"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="C#">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image x:Name="checkImage" Width="30" Height="30" Source="pack://application:,,,/ProjectTracker;component/Icons/GreenCheck.png" />
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=cs_done}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/ProjectTracker;component/Icons/RedX.png" TargetName="checkImage"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid>
```

My `UserControl` currently has about 5 tables with different columns except for these two making it hard to read and tiresome to edit. Is there any way that I could just make these columns reusable such that I can write a table with just

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        </resusedCollumns>
        <!-- Other Columns -->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns cannot be accessed through resources, see [WPF DataGrid Columns in Style or resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716123/wpf-datagrid-columns-in-style-or-resource)

What you can do, is have templates for `DataGridTemplateColumn` in resources.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GreenCheckColumnTemplate">
        <Image x:Name="checkImage" Width="30" Height="30" 
               Source="pack://application:,,,/ProjectTracker;component/Icons/GreenCheck.png" />
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=python_done}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/ProjectTracker;component/Icons/RedX.png" 
    TargetName="checkImage"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
```

and access it using:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Python" 
                               CellTemplate="{StaticResource GreenCheckColumnTemplate}" />
```

**EDIT**

Except I was totally wrong. I was browsing my current project and found that I had done there, what I said could'nt be done.

```
<Window.Resources>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Key="GreenCheckColumn" Header="Python">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="GreenCheckColumn" />

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```