# Binding XML to the WPF DataGrid correctly (Round 2) And creating new DataGrid at Run-Time

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xaml, data-binding

I have a XML file that i'm going to use as a database for my project, this is the xml file i have:

http://pastebin.com/JgyYkn4E

I found this question and tryed it:
[How to bind xml to the WPF DataGrid correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199721/how-to-bind-xml-to-the-wpf-datagrid-correctly)

I want to display *Cadeiras* of each *Semestre*, separately, one in each DataGrid. Changed some minors things to fit my project but it didn't worked, after spending some hours i manage to put it working querying the XElement with this:

```
XElement db = XElement.Load("db.xml");
var cadeira = from elem in db.Descendants("Semestre")
              where elem.Element("Nome").Value == "Semestre 1"
              select elem.Element("Cadeiras");
dataGrid1.DataContext = cadeira;
```

First Question: This worked but i just want to know if this is the best thing to do because, this DataGrid is inside a TabItem (which is inside a TabControl), later i will have to create new TabItems (for each Semestre, with a DataGrid inside with Cadeiras of that respective Semestre) at runtime, without having the XAML binding aid.

Second Question: In XAML, what's the difference between binding as in here [How to bind xml to the WPF DataGrid correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199721/how-to-bind-xml-to-the-wpf-datagrid-correctly/2206547#2206547) and binding as this [WPF Datagrid binding to xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254520/wpf-datagrid-binding-to-xml/4254707#4254707) ?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

-N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do **a lot** via [data templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx), try this example in a XAML-Parser:

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
  <Page.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="data" XPath="GPA/Semestre" Source="http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=JgyYkn4E"/>
  </Page.Resources>
  <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
      <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource data}}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=Nome}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Cadeiras/Cadeira}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Activa" Binding="{Binding XPath=Activa}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nome" Binding="{Binding XPath=Nome}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nota" Binding="{Binding XPath=Nota}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
      </TabControl>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Page>
```

This will create the TabControl and all the DataGrids for you. *(In your sample the Cadeiras do not look very complex so each of them are just one row in a DataGrid, if you need one DataGrid per Cadeira you can do that as well by creating an `ItemsControl` whose `ItemTemplate` is a `DataGrid`)*

---

The difference between the methods in those questions is that they use different classes to represent the XML, normally you would not use `XElement` since that will not support [`XPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.xpath.aspx) in the bindings.

> LINQ to XML objects [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) and [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) do not use XPath. For details, see [How to: Bind to XDocument, XElement, or LINQ for XML Query Results.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165615.aspx)

---

There is no inherently correct way to do this but as there is native binding support for [`XmlDataProviders`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Data.XmlDataProvider.aspx) and thus [`XmlDocuments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) i would go with that unless i have a significant reason not to.

Comment: Wow! First of all, didn't knew i could do all of this just using XAML, amazing, the thing about reading something from XML is that you have a lot of ways and theres no place that have all the ways explained by what they are useful for.

Comment: So did this answer your question? (If so you could [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as such, if not please tell me what you think is missing and i might be able to elaborate)

Comment: (sorry but, i tryed to edit my last post, got some problems, this is the rest of it)

What's the biggest reason to use objects that support XPath instead of using XElement for instance?

About the xaml you posted, i want to be able to insert more data in the dataGrid, is there a "normal" way instead of always creating a new row with "..." in it, so every time the user clicks there, he can add something to that row (and a new row with "..." is created)?

Comment: I looked into adding new rows a bit but couldn't find anything working directly with XML, sorry. The advantage of XPath is that it provides a good way of querying XML.

Comment: The problem i have now that is stopping me from adding new rows is that i can't find a way to call the DataGrid in my code, i was going to try to ask the user to insert the new data outside of the dataGrid and add it using dataGrid.Items.Add( newItem ) (and find out how that Add method can sort the data out itself).

I have already tried using the Name prop in DataGrid but can't find it in code...