# Double list - WPF Toolkit DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I have a datagrid from wpf Toolkit, with the itemsource binded to a `Observable<Item>`. In the `Item` Class, I have another `Observable<bool>` list containing the values to be displayed.

I want to display these values in a custom template. If possible, I want to show other rows as well (which are normal Properties).

How can I perform this? Thank you for your answers.

Update (just to make clear): the second list should be displayed in normal columns, not as master/detail. Imagine the second list would contain 2 `bools`, and the Item class contains 1 extra property. In that case, 3 columns should be shown.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you want to show? Is it like you want to create rows depending on value in Observable<bool>, like row1 to display Item and subsequent rows to display Observable<bool> values in its column? OR you want to create List template for Observable<bool> property in UI?

Comment: I've just updated the question, see above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create second datagrid and bind `SelectedItem.Items` from first grid to itemssource of second. Or you can include second datagrid in row details of your datagrid like this:

```
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

Take a look at [this examples](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGridExamples.aspx) and [this](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html#rowDetails)

Comment: Hi Sergey, thank you for your answer. However, the second list should be displayed in normal columns, not as master/detail. Imagine the second list would contain 2 `bools`, and the Item class contains 1 extra property. In that case, 3 columns should be shown.

Comment: In that case i think you can only create row details, or create a function that will create additional columns at runtime. Is impossible with templates to make variable count of columns, but you can try create custom column template

Comment: this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320089/how-do-i-bind-a-wpf-datagrid-to-a-variable-number-of-columns may help you to

Comment: and may be this is what you want: http://www.brianlagunas.com/index.php/2010/03/08/silverlight-datagrid-populate-dynamic-columns-from-a-child-collection/

Comment: I was hoping there is a better (xaml) way to achieve this... Maybe someone else has a suggestion?

Comment: I will be glad if you can make it through xaml, but very much doubt

Comment: :-) If I however found a solution, I'll post it. Thank you for your answers

Comment: I ended up with adding the columns in code like you suggested in the comment. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can write attached property to datagrid which will create additional columns for you on grid. This property implementor will define binding with individual Observable values.

Comment: Sounds good, but could you specify it in more detail or create a small example? Since I've already tried some kind of this solution, but I did not succeed...

Comment: 1> Create AttachedProperty for grid which will be of type Collection of your ColumnType (This has to be unique class).
2> Define property changed event handler.
3> In event handler, find the values in list. Create DataGridColumns for list. define binding on columns and add them to datagrid columns collection.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that and get back to you later.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, I am wondering where to set the binding on. If I set it on the grid, I do not have the correct binding, since the collection of values is in the ItemCollection. Could you please help me out?

Comment: Hi Rakesh Gunijan, could you please help me out where to set the binding on? Thank you