# Grid in WPF which grows both horisontally and vertically

Tags: wpf, grid

I want to create grid in WPF, which is dynamiccally grows depending on the array length that is in the view model. So in view model I have three props:

```
public string[] HorisontalNames {get;}
public string[] VerticalNames {get;}
public double[,] Values {get;set;}
```

Is that possible? I want it to be simple for view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to remodel your data a bit in your view model, and you can use a solution such as the one provided by Meleak at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4379965/248164.

This attached property will let you bind your `DataGrid` columns to a collection of `DataGridColumn` on your view model. These will be your horizontal names.

The vertical names will be the values of the first column.