# Bind data from 2 tables to datagrid using mvvm

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, datagrid

I am new in MVVM and WPF world. I've been looking for an answer to this question with no luck. 
I wanna bind a datagrid using an ObservableCollection which is in my ViewModel class but the data that feeds my ObservableCollection comes from 2 different tables looking something like this:

```
Table Location:

 - id
 - name
 - locationTypeId
 - isActive

Table LocationType:

 - id
 - name
 - isActive
```

So in my ViewModel class I'm not able to have something like this:

```
public class LocationListViewModel
{
   ObservableCollection< Model.Location> dataSource;
}
```

without modifiying my Model class to something like this:

```
public class Location
{

  public Int32 id {set; get;}
  public String name {get; set;}
  public Int32 locationTypeId {set; get;}
  public Boolean isActive {get; se;}

  //added property to get the location name

  public String locationTypeName {set; get;}

}
```

All the examples I've seen so far for databinding and viewmodels use as example a simple class that comes from a table as a type for the observablecollection.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Just create an additional ViewModel that will serve as Data Item for your rows:

```
public class LocationViewModel: ViewModelBase
{

  public Int32 id {set; get;}
  public String name {get; set;}
  public Int32 locationTypeId {set; get;}
  public Boolean isActive {get; se;}

  //added property to get the location name

  public String locationTypeName {set; get;}

}
```

Then:

```
public class LocationListViewModel
{
   ObservableCollection<LocationViewModel> dataSource {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's something that would work but is there any other way that don't force me to create a class every time I have to do the binding in a similar situation? I would also like to create dynamic views allowing a user to select the columns which he/she would like to see. Is any other way that could help me to solve my problems without having to create a class in the fly?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution mixing 2 approaches:

http://paulstovell.com/blog/dynamic-datagrid

plus the anwser by Fredrik Hedblad to the question:

[How do I bind a WPF DataGrid to a variable number of columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320089/how-do-i-bind-a-wpf-datagrid-to-a-variable-number-of-columns)