# WPF (C#) adding tableData hidden column

Tags: wpf

How can I add a dataTable column that will be hidden in the dataGrid that is binded to that table?

My dataGrid:

```
<DataGrid Name="typesGrid" RowStyle="{StaticResource RowStyleWithAlternation}" CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterCellStyle}" ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsTypeReadOnly}" ItemsSource="{Binding TypesTable}">

    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know your columns at design time, set `AutoGeneratedColumns` to `False` and populate `DataGrid.Columns` with desired columns, setting `Visibility` to `Collapsed` for the column you want to hide. 
If your columns are dynamic, I suggest looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320089/how-do-i-bind-a-wpf-datagrid-to-a-variable-number-of-columns).

Comment: @Yogevnn Then follow the link I provided at the end. You may create collection of columns manually and then "inject" it into your DataGrid.

Comment: This is what i'm doing but I want one of the columns to be hidden

Comment: do you have any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. If you populate columns with your custom collection, then just remove hidden column from that collection or set its Visibility to Collapsed/Hidden.