# Is it possible to populate a datagridview with a variable number of columns

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to present a table of data where every item in the table has a common set of properties but groups of items have properties that are common to just that group.

So for example I might have the objects

```
  Binoculars    Item              Price  Aperture  Magnification  
                10x50 binoculars  £30    50        10
                15x70 binoculars  £79    70        15
  Telescopes    Item              Price  Aperture  Mount  
                90mm refractor    £119   90        AltAz
                90mm refractor    £149   90        Equatorial
  Mounts        Item              Price  Mount  
                AZ1               £79    AltAz
                EQ3               £179   Equatorial
                EQ5               £279   Equatorial
```

At the moment the common properties are held in fields in a database copied to an internal BindingList structure. The custom fields are held in an XML description within a field in that table.

The question is ... is there any suitable structure in c# / silverlight that would allow me to represent this in a single table.

Comment: Could you not just have 6 columns (Product Name, Item, Price, Aperture, Mount and Magnification) and where the item doesn't have a value for that column just have n/a?

Comment: If you're talking about Silverlight or WPF you can just have a custom  usercontrol for each item type. Add a StackPanel to your form and add each control to the stack panel, so it ends up looking like a grid. I've done this before in the past and it works.

Comment: I can't do it with 6 columns and mark some n/a. The example above is just that, an example. In use I do not know what the extra columns will be or how many columns there will be because they are user defined properties.

Equally I don't know how many item types there will be so I can not define a custom user control for those types. The definition of the custom control itself would need to be dynamic (is that possible?) I would imagine that what I need is some control element where I can implement the rendering of the control myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ItemsControl for each of the datagridview.
To generate a particular datagridview you can refer to the following link for your reference:
[How do I bind a WPF DataGrid to a variable number of columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320089/how-do-i-bind-a-wpf-datagrid-to-a-variable-number-of-columns)
The answer by Fredrik Hedblad gives the appropriate solution to your question as to how you can bind the number of columns and the corresponding column behavior during runtime.