# How to do binding between DataGrid header and List<string>

Tags: wpf

I have List and i need to create DataGrid that each item in the List is a column.

So i try to do this

```
<DataGrid Columns="{Binding MyList}" />
```

But this is not working. 
So i also try this

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="MyList"/>
```

also not working.

Comment: DataGrid Columns is ReadOnly. Here's a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320089/how-do-i-bind-a-wpf-datagrid-to-a-variable-number-of-columns

Comment: Thanks !!! 
you solve my problem :)