# WPF databinding in a DataGrid with variable number of columns

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

In my WPF application, I bind data to a `DataGrid`. Let's say I have a class

```
public MyRowData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int string Description { get; set; }
    public CustomClass1 SomeData1 { get; set; }
    public List<CustomClass2> SomeDataList2 { get; set; }
}
```

This class represents one row in the `DataGrid`. My `DataGrid` has a variable number of columns, depending on the length of the `SomeDataList2` list.

In my ViewModel, I currently have the properties

```
public ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> MyColumnCollection { get; set; }
public List<MyRowData> MyTable { get; set; }
```

In my XAML file, I have

```
<DataGrid IsReadOnly="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MyTable, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          viewmodel:DataGridColumnsBehavior.BindableColumns="{Binding MyColumnCollection}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" />
```

where `viewmodel:DataGridColumnsBehavior.BindableColumns` is a class as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4379965/1393899).

`MyColumnCollection` contains some `DataGridColumn` objects like

```
new DataGridTextColumn()
{
    Header = "Id",
    Binding = new Binding("Id")
    {
        Converter = myConverter // some converter I defined earlier
    },
    CanUserSort = false,
    CanUserReorder = false,
    CellStyle = cellStyleDefault, // some style I defined earlier
    ElementStyle = elementStyleRight, // some style I defined earlier
    HeaderStyle = headerStyleRight // some style I defined earlier
};
```

Of course, I also add a `DataGridColumn` for each of the other columns I need, i.e. for `Description`, `SomeData1` and for each element in `SomeDataList2`.

This works perfectly fine so far. But I find it a bit odd to set the styles (`CellStyle`, `ElementStyle`, `HeaderStyle`) in my ViewModel. I would prefer setting these styles in my view (in the `XAML` file).

I have found many examples of how to set styles in `XAML` files, however everything I found so far is made under the assumption that the same styles are applied to all columns. However, in my situation, `string` objects, `CustomClass1` objects and `CustomClass2` should use different styles.

**Now my first question is:** Is there a way in `XAML` to test an object for its type and apply different styles to it depending on the type?

The styles I use also make use of triggers that are bound to some properties. For example, I use

```
DataTrigger myTrigger = new DataTrigger()
{
    Binding = new Binding("SomeDataList2[" + index + "].SomePropteryOfCustomClass2"),
    Value = true
};
```

and apply this `DataTrigger` to a style that is used for displaying the object `SomeDataList2[index]`. Because I use an index in the name of the binding, I am not sure how to write such a binding in `XAML`.

**Now my second question is:** Is there a way to write bindings with indices in `XAML`, so that each object in `SomeDataList2` (where `index` is the objects index in this list) can use a binding to `SomeDataList2[" + index + "].SomePropteryOfCustomClass2` in a trigger?