# how to generate a column in C# code for datagrid that have specific template in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have this code and works good but I want to change it dynamically in C#. Can anyone help me to convert this XAML code to C# code?

**Note:** I set Itemsource of this datagrid in pageload of C# code

**Note:** I want after convert this column to C# code, change AutoGenerateColumns to true

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dg" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ValueA}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ValueB}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Why would you want to convert that to C#? It will be much harder to maintain, and it will not improve anything. You're better off leaving it the way it is.

Comment: Because I want to display two values in a cell, and the number of columns varies

Comment: Why not make the DataTemplate a resource? [Here's an answer that shows how to give a DataGrid dynamic columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4379965/424129).

Comment: I must show Information of a datatable as a table in data grid, because I want do this work dynamically with C# code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoGenerateColumns = false:

```
public partial class MyPage:Page
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeDataGrid();
        Loaded += MyPage_Loaded;

        // don't forget to add the _dataGrid into the page
        this.Content = _dataGrid;
    }

    private void MyPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //_dataGrid.ItemsSource = xxx;
    }

    private void InitializeDataGrid()
    {
        // <DataGrid x:Name="dg" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        //    <DataGrid.Columns>
        //        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        //            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        //                <DataTemplate>
        //                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        //                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ValueA}" />
        //                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ValueB}" />
        //                    </StackPanel>
        //                </DataTemplate>
        //            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        //        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        //    </DataGrid.Columns>
        //</DataGrid>

        // StackPanel and Children
        var stackPanelFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
        stackPanelFactory.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);

        var textBlockFactoryA = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
        textBlockFactoryA.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("ValueA"));

        var textBlockFactoryB = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
        textBlockFactoryB.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("ValueB"));

        stackPanelFactory.AppendChild(textBlockFactoryA);
        stackPanelFactory.AppendChild(textBlockFactoryB);

        // DataTemplate
        var dataTemplate = new DataTemplate
        {
            VisualTree = stackPanelFactory
        };

        // DataGridTemplateColumn
        var templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn
        {
            CellTemplate = dataTemplate
        };

        _dataGrid.Columns.Add(templateColumn);

        // DataGrid
        _dataGrid.Name = "gd";
        _dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    }

    private readonly DataGrid _dataGrid = new DataGrid();
}
```

AutoGenerateColumns = true:

```
public partial class MyPage:Page
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeDataGrid();
        Loaded += MyPage_Loaded;

        // don't forget to add the _dataGrid into the page
        this.Content = _dataGrid;
    }

    private void MyPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //_dataGrid.ItemsSource = xxx;
    }

    private void InitializeDataGrid()
    {
        // <DataGrid x:Name="dg" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        //    <DataGrid.Columns>
        //        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        //            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        //                <DataTemplate>
        //                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        //                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ValueA}" />
        //                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ValueB}" />
        //                    </StackPanel>
        //                </DataTemplate>
        //            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        //        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        //    </DataGrid.Columns>
        //</DataGrid>

        //// StackPanel and Children
        //var stackPanelFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
        //stackPanelFactory.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);

        //var textBlockFactoryA = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
        //textBlockFactoryA.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("ValueA"));

        //var textBlockFactoryB = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
        //textBlockFactoryB.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("ValueB"));

        //stackPanelFactory.AppendChild(textBlockFactoryA);
        //stackPanelFactory.AppendChild(textBlockFactoryB);

        // DataTemplate
        var dataTemplate = new DataTemplate
        {
            //VisualTree = stackPanelFactory
        };

        // DataGridTemplateColumn
        var templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn
        {
            CellTemplate = dataTemplate
        };

        _dataGrid.Columns.Add(templateColumn);

        // DataGrid
        _dataGrid.Name = "gd";
        _dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    }

    private readonly DataGrid _dataGrid = new DataGrid();
}
```