# WPF MVVM Creating rows and columns during runtime

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I create application, where user creates alternatives and criteria. My alternative should have list of criteria, so user can give value for particular criteria in alternative. I would like to present this as a matrix, where rows are alternatives and columns are criteria. User during runtime can create new alternatives and criteria. Both are created using dialogbox, additionally presented in `ListView`. I store them in `ObservableCollection`.

My problem is, that `DataGrid` control doesn't offer easy way to add columns. I look for a solution to my problem, where I could create during runtime both columns and rows. Maybe `DataGrid` is wrong control to use in this scenario. I found some solution, but it doesn't feel right to me. All data, that user inserts, will be later used in solver. Maybe `DataTable` is way to go?

example: https://svitla.com/blog/grid-with-dynamic-number-of-rows-and-columns-part-1

Comment: What type of control would be in "criteria", textbox, dropdown? Can users add their own values or just select predefined?

Comment: Simple textbox. Most probably only numbers. User can add their own values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I bind a WPF DataGrid to a variable number of columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320089/how-do-i-bind-a-wpf-datagrid-to-a-variable-number-of-columns)